# jQuery creating element names

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Hey weird question but I am writing some code and I want to clean it up... The code goes as follows...

```
function (item){
    if(item == "1")
        $('div').show();
    if(item == "2"
        $('div1').show();
}
```

I tried something like

```
function (item)
   var $div = div+item;
   $($div).show()
```

Thanks

Comment: What is `div1`? Is that an ID or class? `div1` on its own will not match any element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function (item){
    $("#div" + (item > 1 ? (item - 1) : "")).show();
}
```

Assuming you mean `#div` + n, since `div1` is not a valid selector. However, the logic should be the same no matter what the prefix of your actual selector is.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/XXSTy/

For information on the conditional operator, [check this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator).

Comment: @sausageRolls: No problem, you too!

Answer (score 0):

There are several errors in your code.

- 2nd `if` statement is missing `)`
- you are trying to find `<div1>` element

There is **no** `div1` element. If you want to refer element IDs you must use "#" so it becomes `$('#idofthediv')`.

Your code is a bit confusing and it is not clear if you want to search for IDs, element names or it is mixed.

If you want to search for IDs `div` and `div1` then just rename 1st id to `div0` and the code will get cleaner (or better `div1` and `div2`):

```
function (item) {
  $("#div" + (item - 1)).show(); 
}
```